# read data from serial device into array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, stream, serial-port

I have a device, /dev/ACMTTY0 which streams data; or rather, for now, random integers 0 - 100.

The device, /dev/ACMTTY0 streams continuously.

But, I still don't know how to read a serial data stream into an array in C++
(properly) For now, I am trying to send it to the screen so i can see what is happening.
when I run my program, here is what happens, I get some numbers which might be valid, I get some -1's and then the program exits, at a random point. I intended it to exit at EOF, but it exits before that? Is EOF appropriate for a stream?

```
sudo ./getc /dev/ttyACM0 
53
50
10
56
-1
-1
```

Any how, I shouldn’t be getting -1 ever, so i don’t know what that is about.
Additionally, The numbers are still streaming. So I dont understand why the program exits.
For more odd behaviour, the program may stream several hundred numbers before exiting, or may stream 2.

Is there something I am doing wrong here:?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <iostream>
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
using namespace std;

 FILE * pFile = NULL;
 int c = 0;
 pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   // pFile=fopen ("fake.dat","r");
      if ( !(pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r")) ) {
        std::cout << argv[1] << " Couldn't open serial port for communication.\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

  if (pFile == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
  else
  {
    do {
      c = getc (pFile);
      std::cout << c << "\n";
    } while (c != EOF);
    fclose (pFile);
  std::cout << c << "\n";
//sleep(2);
      }
  return 0;
}
```

I can read my fake data (file) just fine.

Comment: You need to start by writing code.  If you come upon a concrete question with that code, then post it here.

Comment: Apart from anything else, your protocol is insufficiently specified. Floats in what format?  I suspect an ASCII text representation, but this is not clear.  open the device and try reading from it, ie. write some code as suggested by @JohnZwinck.

Comment: "contentiously" or "continuously"?

Answer (score 1):

You read the device just like a file and parse it. Let's suppose the stream goes:

$1,2,3,4...$4,5,6,7

where $ is your sentinel character. You can't do anything until you see the $ so just discard any leading numbers. Then you'd iteratively hunt for the next comma, fish out the digits and atoi them. Naturally you'd reset your thermocouple number to zero at the $ and increment it at each comma. If you're lucky atoi won't complain about the commas so you don't even need to copy the digits to anywhere else before atoi-ing them, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: `strtol` instead of `atoi`... works a cinch AND tells you what character marked the end of the number.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, a character read of -1 **is** an EOF (usually). If a /dev/ device is returning EOF, it means that no more data is available to read (the device hasn't produced it yet). The two "-1"s at the end of your output are happening here:

```
do {
  c = getc (pFile);
  std::cout << c << "\n";
} while (c != EOF);
fclose (pFile);
std::cout << c << "\n";
```

When an EOF is encountered, it is outputted once, then the loop breaks, then the file is closed, then the EOF is outputted AGAIN, before the program ends. This is the source of your two "-1"s.

If you don't want to output the "-1"s, here's how to revise this code snippet:

```
c = getc(pFile);      //read before entering the loop
while (c != EOF) {    //compare before loop, rather than after
  std::cout << c << '\n';
  c = getc(pFile);
}
fclose(pFile);
```